# How to add a smooth line of best fit to a hexbin graph on R

Tags: r

It seems trivial to add a linear line of best fit in the form of

```
type="r"
```

in

```
hexbinplot(y ~ x, type="r")
```

However, when "smooth" replaces "r", as the manual tells one to do, the graph is overlaid with the error message "panel.hexloess is no longer available". Is there another way to add a loess line or similar?

Note: I tried to add a picture but I don't seem to have the requisite "reputation" to do so.

Comment: It would help to post your full code with a data set sample in order to get better help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The data isn't mine to share in full. Maybe I'll be allowed to share pictures in the comments? It wouldn't let me in the main body.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/OBbbrZe.png

Comment: As you can see, the black linear line of best fit looks great. I've tried to overlay the red line using hexVP.loess, but this is meant for M vs A graphs (mine is not) and seems offset. It actually moves around depending on the size of my window.